# Excel: re-open most recently closed workbooks on next startup

Tags: excel, vba, exit-code, startupscript

I commonly work multiple workbooks simultaneously (5, 6, 7+) and this usually deters me from restarting my computer b/c I don't feel like going through the hassle of saving, closing and then re-opening the workbooks I was recently working on. 
I'm wondering if there is a way for Excel to remember which workbooks I had open before exiting the program (all workbooks at once) and then having the option to open all of those workbooks the next time Excel starts; essentially, this would be a "session restore". To add the cherry on top, it would be great to have a checklist at startup prompting me to choose which workbooks I want to open, in case I don't want to open all of them. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for a vba solution or something that's part of vanilla excel?

Comment: `Workbook_Open()` + `Application.RecentFiles` + `FileSystemObject` checking last modified date or a recent file = a solution I am too lazy to fully write up.

Comment: @FairlyLegit: I assume VBA is the only way to go about this, which I am perfectly comfortable with. I just don't know where to get started.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is you could create another workbook, which would be your open close workbook. Then you could use some code along the lines of

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Dim TotalNum as Long
For Each wb in Application.Workbooks
    TotalNum = TotalNum + 1
    Range("A" & TotalNum) = wb.FullName
    If wb.Name <> ActiveWorkbook.Name Then
        wb.close
    End If
Next wb
```

This code will write out the locations of each file you have open on the workbook. Please note it will also close every workbook that you have open. If you don't want it to do that remove the `wb.close` line.

This following code opens all of those workbooks that were written on the sheet by the previous code.

```
Dim wb as Workbook
For i = 1 to Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Range("A" & i))
Next i
```

How I would use this is make a blank workbook and put two command buttons on it. One will be the "Save Open Workbooks" button and the other will be the "Open Saved Workbooks" button. Then simply click the "Save Open Workbooks" button, save the current workbook, restart your computer, open up the workbook where you placed the two buttons, then click the open button. That should do the trick.

Comment: the "SaveOpenWorkbooks" macro is not working properly. It opens the first wkbk in the sequence (i=1) but fails for the second wkbk (i=2). Error message: **Run-time error '1004':
" could not be found. Check the spelling of the file name, and verify that the file location is correct. If you are trying to open the file from your list of most recently used files, make sure that the file has not been renamed, moved, or deleted.**
When debugging, I see that after the first "Set wb" command, an unrelated add-in I have is called & ran, probably the reason for '" could not be found.'

Answer (score 0):

if you want, you can adjust this function, I have used comment by Brad to do it for the purpose of my job and I do not have much time to adjust it to general case

```html
Private Function offer_recent_IF_SPEC() As Workbook
Dim file As Variant, ans As Boolean
Set offer_recent_IF_SPEC = Nothing
For Each file In Application.RecentFiles
 If file.Name Like "*_COMPLETE_*" Then
    ans = False
    ans = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="IF SPEC document is not opened, do you wish to open " & file.Name & " ?", Title:="IF_SPEC to open", Default:=False, Type:=4)
    If ans Then
        Workbooks.Open file.Name, UpdateLinks:=0
        'Debug.Print Mid(file.Name, InStrRev(file.Name, "\") - 1)
        Set offer_recent_IF_SPEC = Workbooks(Mid(file.Name, InStrRev(file.Name, "\") + 1))
        Exit For
    End If
 End If
Next file
    If Not ans Then
        MsgBox "You do not have opened GBL_COMPLETE excel", vbCritical, "GBL_COMPLETE not opened"
        End
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest a modifications to FailyLegit code, on the part that you open the files:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sWorkbook, sWorksheet As String

sWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.Name
sWorksheet = ActiveSheet.Name

For i = 1 To Workbooks(sWorkbook).Worksheets(sWorksheet).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Workbooks(sWorkbook).Worksheets(sWorksheet).Range("A" & i))
Next i
```

When the macro opens the first file of the list it looses focus, making the reference to the next file be searched on the recently opened file, not the listing.
This fixes it.

Thanks for the code FairlyLegit!